# Swift ios select random pair of questions

Tags: ios, swift

From my code below I have created a math addition app where it will be:

```
lbNum1.text = String(randomItem) +lbNum1.text = String(randomItem)
```

From my code below I use 2 sets of arrays and pull random values from both. What I want to know is what if I only use a fixed set of questions?

For example, this only set of questions will get out if setquestions was called  1+2 ,  3 + 2, 2 +8 , 9 + 7 , 3 + 6 and none of the set of pair will repeat and it will only repeat if all pair have been round. And also how do I store that set of questions to an array that I could assign to lbNum1 and lbNum2?

```
func setRandom() {
    let devices = [1, 2, 8, 7, 6]
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(devices.count)))
    let randomItem = devices[randomIndex]

    let devices1 = [2, 3, 2, 9, 3]
    let randomIndex1 = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(devices1.count)))
    let randomItem1 = devices[randomIndex1]

    var a = 100
    lbNum1.text = String(randomItem)
    lbNum2.text = String(randomItem1)
    setResult(randomA: randomItem, randomB: randomItem1)
}
```

code in getting the data, what i want to know is how can i parse the question which is inside desc and assign thos a and b values to  device = [(a, b) as example, (2, 3), (8, 2), (7, 9), (6, 3)] the values of this should be from the api whic is question a and b so that when the questions of the api changed then the set of questions which is the device will also changed. any idea?

```
Alamofire.request("test", method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

            switch(response.result) {
 case .success(_):
                guard let json = response.result.value as! [[String:Any]]? else{ return}
                print(" The Response \(json)")
                for item in json {
```

//this part is a new question i wanted to ask
response data

```
The Response [["sched": 2018-04-19T15:54:24+08:00, "name": Homework, "reward": 100.00, "child": bryan, "reward_desc": , "type": homework, "status": {
    name = ongoing;
}, "desc": {
  "questions" : [
    {
      "b" : 2,
      "a" : 1
    },
    {
      "b" : 3,
      "a" : 2
    },
    {
      "b" : 2,
      "a" : 8
    },
    {
      "b" : 9,
      "a" : 7
    },
    {
      "b" : 3,
      "a" : 6
    }
  ],
  "operation" : "+"
}, "date_created": 2018-04-30T09:46:44.963028+08:00, "id": 268, "parent": bryan, "occurrence": {
    name = once;
}, "date_modified": 2018-05-12T15:10:09.000152+08:00]]
```

Comment: Can you please be a bit more clear about your problem statement.

Comment: i want to use fix set of pair questions  1+2 , 3 + 2, 2 +8 , 9 + 7 , 3 + 6  and not from random values from device and devices1

Answer (score 0):

If you want a fixed set of questions, you can simply use an Array of Tuples instead of 2 different arrays, i.e.

```
let device = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (8, 2), (7, 9), (6, 3)]
let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(device.count)))
let randomItem = device[randomIndex]

lbNum1.text = String(randomItem.0)
lbNum2.text = String(randomItem.1)
setResult(randomA: randomItem.0, randomB: randomItem.1)
```

Here, you'll have a fixed set of questions from which you can choose randomly.

**Edit:**

```
var device = [(Int, Int)]()
func setRandom()
{
    if device.count == 0
    {
        device = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (8, 2), (7, 9), (6, 3)]
    }
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(device.count)))
    let randomItem = device[randomIndex]
    device.remove(at: randomIndex)
    print(randomItem)
}
```

**Edit: 2**

```
class Device
{
    var first: Int?
    var second: Int?
    var isUsed = false
    init(_ first: Int?, _ second: Int?)
    {
        self.first = first
        self.second = second
    }
}
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    var device = [Device(1, 2), Device(2, 3), Device(8, 2), Device(7, 9), Device(6, 3)]
    func setRandom()
    {
        var filteredDevice = device.filter { $0.isUsed == false }
        if filteredDevice.isEmpty
        {
            for d in device
            {
                d.isUsed = false
            }
            filteredDevice = device
        }
        let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(filteredDevice.count)))
        let randomItem = filteredDevice[randomIndex]
        filteredDevice[randomIndex].isUsed = true
        print(randomItem.first, randomItem.second)
    }
}
```

**Edit 3:**

```
func getrec()
{
    Alamofire.request("test", method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in
        switch(response.result)
        {
        case .success(_):
            guard let json = response.result.value as! [[String:Any]]? else{
                return
            }
            if let arr = json as? [[String:Any]], let dict = arr.first, let questions = (dict["desc"] as? [String:Any])?["questions"] as? [[String:Int]]
            {
                for question in questions
                {
                    self.device.append(Device(question["a"] as? Int , question["b"] as? Int))
                }
                print(device)
            }

        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if. you still face any issues.

Comment: everytime serrandom() is being calle how about no set of pair will repeat sir unless all pair are being executed?

Comment: Then that is not random. If you still want to achieve that, you can do so be removing that element from the array once you have used it.

Comment: can you show an example on that idea Sir  just for clarification?

Comment: can you integrate that to the code you give above sir>

Comment: Edited answer is so simple and working. I prefer not doing removing(mutating) elements in an array and also not having a global variable. Both are not thread safety

Comment: It is not global. It is a class variable. In order to not repeat the elements, you need to keep the state somewhere if not mutate the array.

Comment: @PGDev , can you open a chat ? your could is working fine but i want to ask one last question in the chat . thanks

Comment: I think the chat option appears on is own. You can ask me whatever doubt you have here.

Comment: @PGDev i have updated the question above please kindly ready if ever you have an idea about it.

Comment: I've updated the answer to resolve your non-mutable array problem.

Comment: sir can you help me on parsting the sample response above ? and get those question and put it on device where a and b are pair

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170897/discussion-between-akorn-durn-kurvirck-and-pgdev).

Comment: Hi , @PGDev are yo u there?

Comment: print(device) no data and not printing so it means its not working sir

Answer (score 0):

Simple tuple will solve a fixed combination of questions. As per your reqirement none of the set of pair will repeat and it will only repeat if all pair have been round. We have to maintain the `numberOfTimesUsed` for each pair. Lets have we have a set of three questions, if question2 is taken by random, until question1 and question3 used question2 should not come. Please refer the below code and lemme know if you are not clear or if i missed any case.

```
    import Foundation

    extension Array {
        func random() -> Element {
            let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.count)))
            return self[randomIndex]
        }
    }

    class Question {
        let firstValue: Int
        let secondValue: Int
        var numberOfTimesUsed: Int = 0

        init(firstValue: Int, secondValue: Int) {
            self.firstValue = firstValue
            self.secondValue = secondValue
        }
    }

    var questions = [Question(firstValue: 1, secondValue: 2), Question(firstValue: 3, secondValue: 2), Question(firstValue: 2, secondValue: 8)]

    for x in 1...10 {
        let mininumTimesUsedForAnyQuestion = questions.sorted(by: {$0.numberOfTimesUsed < $1.numberOfTimesUsed}).first!.numberOfTimesUsed

        let question = questions.filter({ question in question.numberOfTimesUsed == mininumTimesUsedForAnyQuestion}).random()
        question.numberOfTimesUsed += 1
        print(question.firstValue, question.secondValue, question.numberOfTimesUsed)
    }
```

**Notice:** For loop will print first 3 in some order, then it will repeat.

Comment: Yes.. How can i help you ?

Comment: I have updated my question above, hope you can help me with that

Comment: its about parsing the questions and appending it to device